# PHP 'Insert Into' Query Returning error result on Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I php code that will insert into database but it always returns false even if it is inserting values into the database.

Here is my code: PHP

```
<?php 
require_once 'connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['borrowBook']))
{
    newBorrowRequest();
}

function newBorrowRequest()
    {
        $b_id = $GLOBALS['db']->real_escape_string($_POST['b_id']);
        $userID = $GLOBALS['db']->real_escape_string($_POST['userID']);
        $dateBorrowed = $GLOBALS['db']->real_escape_string($_POST['dateBorrowed']);
        $remarks = $GLOBALS['db']->real_escape_string($_POST['remarks']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_requestbook`(`b_id`, `userID`, `dateBorrowed`, `remarks`) VALUES ('$b_id','$userID','$dateBorrowed','$remarks')";
                
        if($GLOBALS['db']->query($sql))
        {
            $GLOBALS['db']->close();
            header("location:../../admin/Book-Items.php?r=success", true);
        }
        else
        {
            header("location:../../admin/Book-Items.php?r=failed", true);
        }
    }

>?
```

And here is my Ajax Code:

```
<script>
$("#borrowBook").click(function(event) {
                var bookID = $("#bookBorrow").val();
                var userID = $("#borrowBook").val();
                var d = new Date();

                var month = d.getMonth()+1;
                var day = d.getDate();

                var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
                    (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
                    (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

                

                $.ajax({
                    url: '../assets/php/functions-book.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {borrowBook: 'true', b_id: bookID, userID: userID, dateBorrowed: output, remarks: $("#remarks").val() },
                    success: function(result) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        //window.location.reload();
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
</script
```

There is something wrong with the php query, it will not iterate with the condition thus, it will call the ajax error function.

**[EDITED]**

I solved this by changing 'header("location:../../admin/Book-Item.php?r=success");' to 'header("location:../../admin/Book-Items.php?r=success");'. It was a wrong call.

My problem now is, after success the header remains. It can't be replace by the new header that I want to change. I already changed the php code to the latest.

Comment: share complete error message ?

Comment: Hi @NikleshRaut, thank you for commenting. Here is what I got in console:
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8012/lms/admin/Book-Item.php?r=success 404 (Not Found)

Comment: remove_header() should be header_remove(); -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php

Comment: Hi @Synthetx, I already removed the remove_header() from the code but still it is the same error. The moment I tried to fire the php function, it will successfully  excecute. However, the ajax result will return an error.:
:8012/lms/admin/Book-Item.php?r=success:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Sounds like your file isn't there.. Have you double checked the path and filename? Might be worth trying an absolute URL for the Location header too (not required, but may help identify errors).